# Org-mode strike-through color

Tags: emacs, org-mode, emacs-faces

Strike-through texts (like this: +text+) in Org-mode are black by default. I want to make them gray. The problem is, I can't find the place to customize it. I've tried `M=x describe-face`, and the result is "default face", which is puzzling. Doesn't Org-mode have a place to configure the strike-through color?

Comment: What version of org-mode are you using? In my 7.9.1 strike +text+ don't change color, only a strike line appears.

Comment: Mine is 7.7. My point is, I want it to change color.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the docs, strike-through is *not* a face, but an attribute of the text/face which in this case is imposed on top of whatever face is in effect (like, default-face). In other words, you cannot customize it using customize face.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Customize the `org-emphasis-alist` variable with <kbd>M-x customize-variable</kbd>. Find the list entry where the "marker character" is `+` and choose the "Font-lock-face" option in the "Value menu" popup. Input the value of a face of your choosing, whose exact look you can customize the usual way, for example with <kbd>M-x customize-face</kbd>.

Or, more succinctly:

```
(require 'cl)   ; for delete*
(setq org-emphasis-alist
      (cons '("+" '(:strike-through t :foreground "gray"))
            (delete* "+" org-emphasis-alist :key 'car :test 'equal)))
```

Comment: This answer is still relevant and works, but the `cl` package has been deprecated as of Emacs 27. Maybe an approach that doesn't depend on `cl` is to define a custom `org-custom-strike-through` face and apply it to the `custom-set-variables` under `org-emphasis-alist`. I can see that somewhat recently there is a patch for a `defface` on strike-through face in `org-faces`, but it's not been merged (idk, I might be mistaken)? [source](https://orgmode.org/list/87a74najrb.fsf@gnu.org/t/)

Comment: @mnestorov `cl` is deprecated, but `cl-lib` is alive and well, and defines `cl-delete` which is the equivalent of `delete*`. Of course, you could do it without either, but it would be less elegant/succinct.

Comment: Yep, that's true :) I just thought it would be a good idea to mention it, since I recently looked into what's happening with `cl`.